# Function symmetric about its inputs

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, terminology

What does a function *'symmetric in terms of its inputs'* mean? Does it mean $f(x,y) = f(y,x)$ or it means the function is only defined over $\{(x,y) : x = y\}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first interpretation is correct.  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_function